# Código dejó de validar el campo email

Tags: python, pyqt5

estoy trabajando en windows, python y sqlite3 para una app y no me valida el formato del email, puedo ingresar cualquier formato y no arroja mensaje con error, parte del código es:

```
class LoginWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.contract_display_button = None  # New attribute for contract display button
        self.setup_ui()

    def setup_ui(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        form_layout = QFormLayout()

        self.email_entry = QLineEdit()
        form_layout.addRow(QLabel('Email:'), self.email_entry)

        self.password_entry = QLineEdit()
        self.password_entry.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        form_layout.addRow(QLabel('Password:'), self.password_entry)

        self.login_button = QPushButton('Login')
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.login)
        form_layout.addRow(self.login_button)

        self.create_account_button = QPushButton('Create Account')
        self.create_account_button.clicked.connect(self.show_create_account_dialog)
        form_layout.addRow(self.create_account_button)

        layout.addLayout(form_layout)

    def login(self):
        email = self.email_entry.text().strip()
        password = self.password_entry.text()

        if not email:
            QMessageBox.information(self, 'Login', 'Please enter your email!')
            return

        if not self.validate_email(email):  # Email validation
            QMessageBox.information(self, 'Login', 'Invalid email format!')
            return

        user = self.parent.database.c.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', (email,)).fetchone()

        if user is None:
            QMessageBox.information(self, 'Login', 'User does not exist!')
        else:
            stored_password = user[4]
            if hashlib.md5(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() == stored_password:
                QMessageBox.information(self, 'Login', 'Login successful!')
                if self.contract_display_button is not None:
                    self.contract_display_button.setEnabled(True)
            else:
                QMessageBox.information(self, 'Login', 'Incorrect password')

    @staticmethod
    def validate_email(email):
        pattern = r'^[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w+$'
        return re.match(pattern, email)

    def show_create_account_dialog(self):
        dialog = CreateAccountDialog(self.parent)
        dialog.exec_()
```